Determine 3-point function by conformal symmetry
I already posted question to math stack but I haven't yet gotten answer. So, I ask here.
I'd like to know a form of functions (called 3-point function) that have symmetry under some transformation.
The symmetry is followings.
$G_{ijk}$ is a function over $\mathbb{C}^3$ and satisfies
$$G_{ijk}(z_1,z_2,z_3)=\prod_{l=1}^3(\dfrac{dw}{dz_l}(z_l))^{h_l}(\overline{\dfrac{dw}{dz_l}(z_l))}^{\overline{h_l}}G_{ijk}(w(z_1),w(z_2),w(z_3))\ \ \ (9.1)$$
for all transformation $w$ (I define the set of transformations below).
Each $h_l$ or $\overline{h_l}$ is a fixed real number ($\overline{h_l}$ doesn't mean complex conjugate!). Transformations are rotations$$r_\alpha:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}, z\mapsto e^{i\alpha}z,\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$$ translations $$t_a :\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}, z\mapsto z+a, a\in\mathbb{C}$$
and dilatations $$d_{\tau} :\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}, z\mapsto e^{\tau}z, \tau\in\mathbb{R}$$.
$G_{ij}$ case is easily proved in a text book  (axiom 2 and axiom 4 are the symmetry I mentioned above).

In the same way, I tried to prove for $ijk$ case.
$$G_{ijk}(z_1,z_2,z_3)=G_{ijk}(z_{13},z_{23},0)=z_{23}^{-(h_1+h_2+h_3)}\overline{z_{23}}^{-(\overline{h_1}+\overline{h_2}+\overline{h_3})}G_{ijk}(\dfrac{z_{13}}{z_{23}},1,0)$$
However there is a still degree of freedom of function $G(z):=G_{ijk}(z,1,0)$. How can we restrict degree of freedom up to complex number?

Please don't post images/text for text and equations. Instead, type the relevant passage using MathJax.

@TobiasFünke I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with this site. Is is it prohibited to use image of reference instead of typing?

See this Meta Post, for example.

@TobiasFünke Thanks for giving reference. I agree with parts of that but as a person in science, I think it's not reasonable to retype same things.  Contents in textbook are already optimized for readers by author. I typed my question and just used image to show an example for those who are not familiar with. If questioners find similar question, they just past the link for getting good answer and don't rewrite all. Is there difference?

Crossposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5014043/11127

Is is it prohibited to use image of reference instead of typing? It’s strongly discouraged. The most-upvoted answer to the meta post provided by Tobias says “Screenshots of text have no place on this site”, which I think is quite clear and quite strong. Your account won’t get suspended from asking questions for posting images of text and/or math, but such posts may get downvoted or not answered. The site has standards and you should respect them after being made aware of them.

Use special conformal transformations.

@Ghoster Thanks for advice. I understand. I should respect their standard. I won't screenshots from next time.

@ConnorBehan Thanks but special conformal transformations are not required for correlation functions in these axioms. I also think if there is special conformal covariance I can prove this lemma.

If your book says 3pt functions can be fixed up to a constant even if they aren't invariant under special conformal transformations then it's wrong.

@ConnorBehan Thanks. Yes, this book doesn't require special conformal invariance. I conclude that this book is wrong.
